# How do I save min value price?

Tags: php, arrays, database, wordpress, multidimensional-array

How can I solve this?

```
<?php       
    $pricemin=array();
    for($index = 0; $index < count($_POST['floor_plans']); $index++){
        $pricemin[]=$_POST['floor_plans'][$index]['fave_plan_price'];    
    }
    $prices=min(print_r($pricemin));
    update_post_meta( $prop_id, 'fave_property_price', sanitize_text_field( $prices) );

?>
```

How to I save min value?

**Edit update post mata**

Comment: What do you mean by "save" here? How will you use the saved value?

Comment: What is not working for you? how do you try to read that value?

Comment: And where the `$prop_id` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $pricemin ends up being an array of numbers, use min($pricemin).
Or using array_column:

```
$pricemin = min(array_column($pricemin[]=$_POST['floor_plans'], 'fave_plan_price'));
```